# How to retrieve language specific image from assets in c# metro application

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I have c# metro application where are stored localized images in the assets.

```
Assets
  cs-CZ
    Car1.jpg
    Car2.jpg
    Car3.jpg
    Car4.jpg
  en-US
    Car1.jpg
    Car2.jpg
    Car3.jpg
    Car4.jpg
    Car5.jpg
    Car6.jpg
    Car7.jpg
```

I would like to load all CarXX.jpg language specific images into the list and check if the image exists (the code should be dynamic so if somebody adds new images it will loads the new ones without changing any parameter in the application). I don't know how to check if the image exists for specified language. If the application runs in cs-CZ it must return 4 images, it the application runs in en-US, it must returns 7 images.

I have this code:

```
/// ...
int index = 1;
while (true)
{
    string carPictureName = String.Format("Car{0}.jpg", index++);

    // TODO: CHECK IF FILE EXISTS IN THE ASSET FOR SPECIFIED LANGUAGE
    bool fileExists = CheckIfFileExists(carPictureName);

    if (fileExists)
    {
        pictures.Add(carPictureName);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if there's a directory named after the current language, and load all images in it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you reference a "logical" bitmap in the XAML and the resource loaded will detect the current culture and load the correct image.  It's generally a good idea to have non-specific cultures as well (like "en" and "cs" in case you're in a culture like en-CA but still want to show language-specific resources.

For an example application that does this, see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa (it also includes overriding the culture).